# Only In IE : combotree inside the form does't work

Tags: internet-explorer-11, jquery-easyui

EasyUi combtree dose't working inside the **form** tag, It's fine other than **form** tag

**Mark Up**

```
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="searchfolder"><?php echo \Application\Plugin\Common::z_xlt('Move to Category'); ?></label>
    <div class="custom-dropdownclass custom-documents">
       <inputclass="form-control easyui-combotree " ng-value="currentdocument.category" data- realcatcode="{{currentdocument.category}}" name="parent" id ="searchfolder" data- options="input:searchfolder">
     </div>
 </div>
<form>
```

**Script**

```
$http({
 method: 'post',
 url: basePath + '/documents/documents/ajax',
 data: data
}).then(function(response) {
 $('#searchfolder').combotree('loadData', $scope.getDirectTreeComboData(response.data.directorytree));
                        $('#newfolder_parent').combotree('loadData', 
 $scope.getDirectTreeComboData(response.data.directorycombotree));
  });
```

**Error** [Image of console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSkaH.png)

Comment: Do you mean it works well outside the form tag or without using the form tag? it is very strange. When you call the above JavaScript script? Please check it and make sure you are calling it after page load. Besides, try to use F12 developer tools to check the html elements and verify whether the id value is correct. If still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Another thing, it seems that you are using angularjs, please make sure you have added the related polyfills.

Comment: I fix my issue just replacing from tag by a div,I know its not good approch but its working, thank you